# libGDX: How to handle collisions for sprites from the Tiled object layer?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

I am using *libGDX* and *Tiled* to make an RPG. I already have a lot of stuff working: title screen, a testing screen, that has my map loaded on it. I can read the properties I put onto the map and on certain tiles. I can also move around the map and everything, but what I am trying to figure out now is:

How do I render a map object from the object layer and handle collisions?

I am wanting to use Tiled's Object layer for my collision layer. IE: put shapes around certain tiles/areas that I don't want the characters to be able to pass through.

This is what I have so far:

```
package rawct.awakening;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObject;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.MapObjects;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTile;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileLayer.Cell;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMapTileSet;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ObjectMap;

public class GameMap extends TiledMap {
    private String TAG = "GameMap";
    private TmxMapLoader loader = new TmxMapLoader();
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mRender;

    private TiledMap gamemap;
    private TiledMapTileLayer mapTiles;

    private ObjectMap<TiledMapTile, Boolean> Blocked;
    private ObjectMap<TiledMapTile, Boolean> Event;

    private MapObjects mObjects = new MapObjects();
    private MapObject mObj;

    public void draw(OrthographicCamera cam){
        mRender.setView(cam);
        mRender.render();
    // Should render my map object?
        mRender.renderObject(mObj);
    }

    public GameMap(String Map){
        Blocked = new ObjectMap<TiledMapTile, Boolean>();
        Event = new ObjectMap<TiledMapTile, Boolean>();

        gamemap = loader.load("maps/"+Map+".tmx");
        mRender = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(gamemap);
        loadMap(gamemap);
    }

    private Cell getCellAt(float x, float y){
        return mapTiles.getCell((int)x, (int)y);
    }

    private TiledMapTile getTileAt(float x, float y){
        Cell cell = getCellAt(x, y);
        return cell != null ? cell.getTile() : null;
    }

    public boolean isTileBlocked(float x, float y){
        try {
            return Blocked.get(getTileAt(x, y));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void loadMap(TiledMap map) {
        String sI = null;
        Blocked.clear();
        Event.clear();

        try{
            mapTiles = (TiledMapTileLayer)map.getLayers().get(0);
            mObjects = map.getLayers().get("Testing").getObjects();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, e.toString());
        }


        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Objects:"+mObjects.getCount());

        for(Iterator<MapObject> mObjs = mObjects.iterator(); mObjs.hasNext();){
        // I have set just about everything possible(I only have one object at the moment so mObj only gets set once.
            mObj = mObjs.next();
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Obj:"+mObj.getName());
            mObj.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            mObj.setOpacity(1f);
            mObj.setVisible(true);

//          try {
//              Method Test = getClass().getDeclaredMethod((String) mObj.getProperties().get("Func"));
//              Test.invoke(this);
//          } catch (Exception e) {
//              Gdx.app.log(TAG, e.toString());
//          }
        }

        Array<String> sTilesets = new Array<String>();
        TiledMapTile tile;

        try {
            for(Iterator<TiledMapTileSet> tilesets = map.getTileSets().iterator(); tilesets.hasNext();){
                    sI = tilesets.next().getName();
                    sTilesets.add(sI);
            }

            int tCount = sTilesets.size;
            for(int i = 0; i < tCount; i++){
                for(Iterator<TiledMapTile> tiles = map.getTileSets().getTileSet(sTilesets.get(i)).iterator(); tiles.hasNext();){
                tile = tiles.next();

                if(tile.getProperties().containsKey("blocked")){
                    //Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Tile:" + tile.getId() + " blocked!");
                }

                if(tile.getProperties().containsKey("name")){
                    //Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Name:" + tile.getProperties().get("name"));
                }

                boolean blocked = Boolean.parseBoolean(tile.getProperties().get("blocked", "false", String.class));
                boolean event = Boolean.parseBoolean(tile.getProperties().get("event", "false", String.class));

                Blocked.put(tile, blocked);
                Event.put(tile, event);
            }
        }
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Map Loaded!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Error:" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public TiledMap getMap(){
        return gamemap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I [answered a similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/70448/41604) over on GameDev recently, having been stymied by the same problem for a while. A thorough Googling eventually led me to [a tutorial](http://siondream.com/blog/games/populate-your-box2d-world-using-the-libgdx-maps-api/) on the subject. And I do mean thorough. It seems to be the only solution to this problem on the entire Internet. Weird.

Anyway. The answer I gave and the tutorial it was based on both use Box2d to handle collision detection. I'd *wholeheartedly* suggest going that route if you're not too far into making your game: Box2d handles quite a bit for you if you use it, but it does mean rethinking a lot of your existing code. Everything to do with movement, basically. If that's what you choose to do, the good old [LibGDX wiki](http://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) can get you started (that's a direct link to the relevant article).

If you don't want to go down that rabbit hole, then the links above still suggest a solution. Where I think you're going wrong is in trying to just draw the `MapObject`s directly. Try this:

```
MapObjects objects = map.getLayers().get("Obstacles").getObjects();

for(MapObject object : objects) {
    if (object instanceof RectangleMapObject) {
        Rectangle rect = ((RectangleMapObject) object).getRectangle();
        // do something with rect...
    }
    else if (object instanceof PolygonMapObject) {
        Polygon polygon = ((PolygonMapObject) object).getPolygon();
        // do something with polygon...
    }
    else if (object instanceof PolylineMapObject) {
        Polyline chain = ((PolylineMapObject) object).getPolyline();
        // do something with chain...
    }
    else if (object instanceof CircleMapObject) {
        Circle circle = ((CircleMapObject) object).getCircle();
        // do something with circle...
    }
}
```

From there you deal with the generated shapes (the `Rectangle` or what have you) rather than the `MapObject`s. They have the methods useful for collision detection, like `overlaps()`, `contains()` and the like. If you're only dealing with one type of shape, then it makes life easier in a non-Box2d game. Use only the `if` statement for `PolygonMapObject`, for instance, and drop the other three.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need a kind of "mapping" for the blocked tiles. So you cant always check if the tile is blocked or not. This would take to long to get the tile. 
 To do so there are different ways but i used this.
I wrote my own "Map". This Map holds a Array at the dimension of my current TiledMap. When i load a Map i do set a value inside of that mapArray so i know, if i can move on that Tile or not. This does look a bit awefull and take some time at bigger maps but it does work.

```
private void setBlocked() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.map.getLayers().getCount(); i++) {
        TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) this.map.getLayers()
                .get(i);
        for (int y = 0; y < layer.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < layer.getWidth(); x++) {
                if (layer.getCell(x, y) != null
                        && layer.getCell(x, y).getTile().getProperties()
                                .containsKey("blocked")) {
                    this.mapArray[x][y] = Config.CANTMOVEONPOSITION;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To debug i render squares and do fill them in the color of the "mapState" likes this:

```
if (this.map != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.map.width; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.map.height; j++) {
                    switch (this.map.mapArray[i][j]) {
                    case Config.CHARSTATE:
                        // green
                        debugger.setColor(0, 1f, 0, Config.DEBUG_ALPHA);
                        break;
                    case Config.CANTMOVEONPOSITION:
                        // black
                        debugger.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, Config.DEBUG_ALPHA + 0.1f);
                        break;
                    case Config.MONSTERSTATE:
                        // red
                        debugger.setColor(1f, 0, 0, Config.DEBUG_ALPHA);
                        break;
                    case Config.MOVETONEXTMAP:
                        // yellow
                        debugger.setColor(1f, 1f, 0, Config.DEBUG_ALPHA);
                        break;
                    default:
                        debugger.setColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        break;
                    }
                    debugger.rect(i * Config.TILE_SIZE, j * Config.TILE_SIZE,
                            Config.TILE_SIZE, Config.TILE_SIZE);
                }
            }
            debugger.end();
        }
```

this isnt optimized! So if you have a big map and just show a small frame it still does draw every square. The `height and width` in this case are the tilecount in height and width.

I hope this does answer your question or you can find your way with that help. 

Regards

Comment: I'm afraid your answer had nothing to do with the q which was about rendering map objects from the object layer.  Doing it on a tile level assumes a  tile layer and a cell there leading to the somewhat horrible full map tile parsing and subsequent duplicate array in your solution.  Using map objects as described in the q and the first answer is infinitely more powerful since map objects can easily be morphed into b2d objects and are not confined to being a single cell size.